# Listview highlight on press and ripple different in app and on widget... how do i change widget values?

Tags: android, listview, colors, widget, styles

So I have a listview in my app and it seems that the AppTheme value "colorControlHighlight" changes the colors for ripple and onclick row in that listview to (blue).  However I made a listview with identical xml attributes that relate to color on a widget and for some reason the ripple and on press colors are still the default color (white).  If I change the `android:listselector` attribute for the listview on my widget, it works but it doesn't act the same and the ripple effect is gone. How it acts; after I change listselector it stays blue unless I press a different row on the list. This is not what I want (is this because i haven't set onclick actions yet? or is this how that attribute is designed to work?).  Any help would be appreciated.

This is my app activity listview

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/AppUrlList"
    android:background="@color/dark_black"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:divider="@color/faded_blue"
    android:clickable="true"
    />
```

now this is my widget listview

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:dividerHeight="2px"
    android:divider="@color/faded_blue"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:id="@+id/WidgetListView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

now this is my apptheme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/faded_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/bright_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/bright_blue</item>
```

thanks for the suggestions to improve my question i'm new here

Comment: It is very helpful to actually link some of your code... !

Comment: Widget Listview
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:dividerHeight="2px"
        android:divider="@color/faded_blue"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/WidgetListView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

Comment: app listview
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/AppUrlList"
        android:background="@color/dark_black"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:divider="@color/faded_blue"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

Comment: You should add that code to your question by using the [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38007082/edit)

Comment: app style
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/faded_blue</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/bright_blue</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/bright_blue</item>

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out i had to do this:

app_list_item.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/AppListTextViewGreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/List_Hint"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/list_background_green"
    style="@style/liststyleGreen"
    />
```

then in list_background_green.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/faded_green" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/faded_green"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

the state_pressed is what defines the color when the list item is pressed (obviously)

and the default background is black.

this works on my widget whereas setting the default colors in the app theme did not change the colors in my widget.

EDIT: forgot to put the ripple selector here too, here it is, and i'll also include how to make it work on versions above api 21.

you have to name the ripple selector the same name as the list selector.  so you would make another xml named "list_background_green" but put it in drawable-v21 folder.  This folder probably won't exist so right click on res folder in android studio and click show in explorer, then create drawable-v21 folder and put the same named xml there.  here is an example.

drawable-v21/list_background_green.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/bright_green">
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:state_selected="true">
                <color android:color="@color/transp_green" />
            </item>
        <item android:state_activated="true">
            <color android:color="@color/transp_green" />
        </item>

        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <color android:color="@color/transp_green" />
        </item>

        <item>
            <color android:color="@color/semi_trans_black" />
        </item>
    </selector>
</item>
```

you want to be careful how transparent you make this value.

```
<color android:color="@color/semi_trans_black" />
```

i couldn't figure out why the selector wasn't showing up for a while and then realized that if this value is too transparent it makes the ripple not show up.  I can't explain why if someone can please do, just warning people because it took me a while to figure out that was the cause. That value is the default background for each textview in the list, so maybe the selectors inherit it's transparency although that doesn't make alot of sense.  I only had to do this on my appwidget, for some reason beyond my current understanding.  In my regular app listview i didn't need to do any of this.  My suspicion is that widgets inherit their theme from the system but i'm not sure of this.

cheers, hope this helps someone.